# mysite https:// I get an unsecured connection failure

Tags: https

[www.tiglidizayn.com](https://www.tiglidizayn.com/cafe-dizayn.html)

I get an unsecured connection failure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiheP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, I think is duo to your cache, please use this website to check the ssl:

```
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.tiglidizayn.com
```